# how to fix the weird error "Operation not permitted"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```sh
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ ./sysupdate
-bash: ./sysupdate: Operation not permitted
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ chmod +x ./sysupdate
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ ./sysupdate
-bash: ./sysupdate: Operation not permitted
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ sudo ./sysupdate
sudo: unable to execute ./sysupdate: Operation not permitted
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ ls -l ./sysupdate
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hadoop hadoop 1102480 Apr 28 07:48 ./sysupdate
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ stat ./sysupdate
  File: ‘./sysupdate’
  Size: 1102480     Blocks: 2160       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 402520      Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1001/  hadoop)   Gid: ( 1000/  hadoop)
Access: 2020-05-08 13:02:31.919594048 +0800
Modify: 2020-04-28 07:48:11.962969475 +0800
Change: 2020-05-08 13:02:29.883603300 +0800
 Birth: -
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ cp /usr/bin/ls ./
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ ./ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.22

Written by Richard M. Stallman and David MacKenzie.
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ chmod --reference=./sysupdate ./ls
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ ls -l ./ls
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hadoop hadoop 117656 May  8 13:02 ./ls
[hadoop@worker-18 tmp]$ ./ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.22

Written by Richard M. Stallman and David MacKenzie.
```

it's weird...

but when i uploaded it to my own server, i can execute it:

```sh
➜ ~ ./sysupdate --version
screen 2.8.5
 built on Mar  8 2020 with GCC 4.8.5
 features: 64-bit AES

libuv/1.34.0
```

so why i can't execute `sysupdate` in server `worker-18`?

the os is CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Comment: Probably the file is set to immutable. Try `sudo chattr -i ./sysupdate`

Comment: you can check attribute using `lsattr ./sysupdate`

Comment: @DigvijayS the result is `-------------e-- ./sysupdate`

Comment: Still facing same issue?

Comment: As far as i know, all files have `e` as a default attribute. From man page `The 'e' attribute indicates that the file is using extents for mapping 
    the blocks on disk.  It may not be removed using chattr(1).
`

Comment: Try raising issue on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @DigvijayS ok, https://superuser.com/questions/1549793/how-to-fix-the-weird-error-operation-not-permitted

Comment: @DigvijayS Why superuser? Isn't https://unix.stackexchange.com/ more appropriate by far?

Comment: @Socowi Yeah. Forgot about it.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me on my RHEL 8 box. Checked (almost) everything, but at the end I found out that the culprit was `fapolicyd` running, which restricts execution policies according to file formats, directories, etc.

Maybe someone else running into this issue might have the `fapolicyd`.

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue. Thought it was selinux but turned out to be fapolicyd.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have SElinux enabled on server?

```
/usr/sbin/sestatus
```

Comment: `SELinux status:                 disabled`

Comment: I also found information that sometimes it can be a virus that is already running under this name.
You can see the output of this command: `ps aux | grep sysupdate` and `ls -la ../`

Comment: yes. exactly speaking, `sysupdate` is a mining program. but what really interests me is why i can execute it @Nigredon

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too, after walking around, maybe the `/tmp` dir is mounted as `noexec`. To check this, execute:

```sh
cat /proc/mounts | grep /tmp
```

If it is mounted as `noexec`, try to remount it as executable:

```sh
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

Maybe SELinux is another reason...

Answer (score -1):

I had this weird error "Operation not permitted" these days and I figured out the solution on my case.
This happened to my new vm on version rhel8 which used for Jenkins building job on non-root privileges. I already run 'chown' of every dirs that involved to build, but still get "Operation not permitted".
Finally I got solution [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening) and [here](https://www.stb.id.au/blog/app-control-for-everyone).

You can use 'fapolicyd-cli -f add /yourdirorfile' to make fapolicyd trust yours.

I just rudely deleted fapolicyd by 'yum remove fapolicyd'. (Just local machine, no need this lol)